# Вывод аргументов шаблонного класса из конструктора

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, конструктор, c++17

Я пытаюсь сделать следующее:

```
template <typename TYPE, size_t COUNT>
class BUFFER
{
public:
    BUFFER(TYPE (&buffer)[COUNT]) : buffer{buffer}{}
private:
    TYPE (&buffer)[COUNT];
};

int ints[100];
BUFFER buffer{ints};
```

В ответ получаю:

```
error: missing template arguments before 'buffer'
```

Должны ли параметры шаблона выводиться из того, что суется в конструктор класса?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так ведь зависит от того, какая версия C++ компилятором поддерживается. Поскольку вывод парметров шаблона из аргументов конструктора появился в C++17.

Например, запуск VC++ 2017 с параметром `/std:c++14` говорит об ошибке, а `/std:c++17` - нет.

Answer (score 1):

Я за ответ @Harry. Но все же предложу Вам использовать make-функции, см. код ниже. Наличие последней исключает необходимость указывать типы вручную, ну и будет работать в С++14 (или C++11, но тогда придется забыть про decltype(auto)).

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class array_view {
public:
    explicit array_view(T (&arr)[N])
        : m_buf(arr)
    {}

    const T& operator[](size_t idx) const {
        return m_buf[idx];
    }

protected:
    T(&m_buf)[N];
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
decltype(auto) make_array_view(T (&arr)[N]) {
    return array_view<T, N>(arr);
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    auto array = make_array_view(arr);
    std::cout << array[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```